# Why zegocloud Video Communication system is not connect in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, zegocloud

I have created a web app using zegocloud to make video calls. When I run this app as an image inside kubernetes the web app runs but the video calling system doesn't find the device inside.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5se1p.png)

I want try to connect video calling like audio and video device found

Comment: You need to explain more. Does the backend do any video thing? any peer-to-peer networking? How does the web client connect to backend?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.